# Is it a good idea to access child class properties in parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

I have learned OOP principles with JAVA as my first language and then I have moved to Python and so this particular feature look bit weird to me, useful though in many cases.

However, I would like to know if it's really advisable.

Following would give error in JAVA, as you can't access property of child class in parent class.

```
class parent(object):
    def print_x(self):
        print self.x


class child(parent):
    x = 10

child().print_x()
```

**PEP8** also gives a warning in this case:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'x' for class 'parent'

code traversal and debug becomes bit problematic in my personal opinion.

Comment: Since you *can* instantiate `parent` on its own, which would produce an error, *yes*, this is problematic. Python is just more dynamic than Java and doesn't check this at compile time. It's still bad code for the same reason as in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is a place where dependency injection would be more appropriate (composition versus inheritance). A "parent" that reaches down into it's "children" questionable at best.

How about something more along the lines of:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, child_instance):
        self.child = child_instance

    def print_x(self):
        print self.child.x

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

child = Child(10)
parent = Container(child)
parent.print_x()
```

There are many advantages to composition in lieu of inheritance in many cases, like this one, and I strongly recommend you research them.

Answer (score 2):

As cleaner way would be to

```
class Parent(object):

    @property
    def x(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def print_x(self):
        print self.x


class Child(Parent):
    x = 10
```